# Simple Tabs - Scroll position CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tabs

Im using the following tabs, which behave like this:
(√ = working as intended, X = not working as intended)

-> When loading page, Tab 1 is active √

*Manually scrolling to bottom of Tab 1

-> Clicking Tab 2, Page scrolls automatically to top of Tab 2 √

*Manually scrolling to middle of Tab 2

-> Clicking Tab 1 again, Page scrolls to top of Tab 1 X

At this point (2nd visit of a tab) it should save the last scroll position, instead scrolling to top again.

It should go like this:

-> Scroll Tab 1 manually to ex. Height:20px

-> Click Tab 2, scroll to top automatically.

-> Scroll Tab 2 manually to Height:50px

-> Click Tab 1, scroll was saved on height:20px

-> Click Tab 2, scroll was saved on height:50px

-> Click Tab 1, scroll still saved on height:20px

-> Click Tab 2, scroll still saved on height:50px

-> Click Tab 3, automatically scroll to top because its the first visit to tab 3.

How can i achieve such function?

```js
document.getElementById('tab').style.height = document.querySelector(`#tab div`).getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px'

const btn = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('button'))
btn.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    btn.forEach((item) => {
      item.classList.remove('active')
    })
    item.classList.add('active')
    document.getElementById('tab').setAttribute('data-tab', index)

    const currentTab = document.querySelector(`#tab div:nth-of-type(${index + 1})`);
    document.getElementById('tab').style.height = currentTab.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px'
  })
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
}

.tabs>* {
  width: 100%;
}

.tabs[data-tab='1'] {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.tabs[data-tab='2'] {
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}

.tabs[data-tab='3'] {
  transform: translateX(-300%);
}

.tabs[data-tab='4'] {
  transform: translateX(-400%);
}

.inliner {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.inliner>* {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
  word-spacing: normal;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <button> Tab 1</button>
  <button> Tab 2</button>
  <button> Tab3</button>

  <div id="tab" class="tabs inliner">
    <div>
      <h2>Content 1 </h2>

    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam </h2>

    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>How can i save the scroll position after 1st visit of a tab?</p>
```

In case i did not explain too well: I want to achieve this:

> 1st visit of Tab: scroll to top. (Already in code)

> Save last scroll position of specific tab

> When revisiting a Tab, dont scroll to top, instead display the last scroll position from 1st visit of that tab.

([JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xcf19s2/1/))

Also, I dont need it to keep saved on pageload. I just need it for the current visit of my webpage.

Thanks

Comment: what is exactly happening , your code works for tabbing scroll,

Comment: have you tried `sessionStorage` combined with getting the scroll position?